# Dotted progress bar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to create a dotted progress bar and I hope someone here can help me with the implementation. It should look something like the following sketch, but with black background. The progress is visualized using circles that change from gray to white when a certain percentage is reached. Ideally the number of dots should dynamically adjust to the bar's width.

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|  O    O    O    O    O    O    O    O    O    O  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Can this be done using styles alone or do I have to create a custom control?

Comment: you can probably do it setting progressbar `Background` property with custom brush

Comment: Having trouble visualizing exactly what you're after. Do you have a better visual example? I'm thinking it could be done with just some style template edits.

Comment: The bar should look like [this](http://imgur.com/VOwjmAT). Depending on the width every, say, 5% percent an animation is triggered that changes a circle's color from gray to white.

Comment: I could think of several ways to do this both with and without just the default style template and some customization. Easiest would probably be to just plop a Path over top of it with the ellipses cut out and change the left/right bars to gray/white respectively so as it acts as a normal progress bar it just gives the illusion of loading dots as the progress bar does its thing underneath the holes in the path. If I have some free time later I'll try and squeeze out a minute to make a concept or two, but it is a Monday after a holiday break so no promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chris W says in the comments, there are a few ways to approach this through styling and templating alone. Here's an example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="NormalDot" TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="10" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="10" />
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="ProgressDot" BasedOn="{StaticResource NormalDot}"
                       TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="White" />
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Track" Orientation="Horizontal"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource NormalDot}" />
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Indicator" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                                <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ProgressDot}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Value, ElementName=_slider}"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Slider x:Name="_slider" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The basic idea is two **StackPanel** containers, each holding ten **Ellipse** elements. The second **StackPanel** is layered over the first using a **Grid**, however its width varies in line with the progress bar's current value, which then gives the desired effect of the white "dots" appearing as progress increases. If you wanted a different number of dots then you'd increase or decrease the number of **Ellipse** elements: just remember you need the same number in each panel.

A variation of this technique would replace the **ItemsControl**s, **StackPanel**s and **Ellipse**s with a pair of **Rectangle** elements filled with custom **DrawingBrush**es.

The weakness of both approaches given your stated requirements is that (a) you don't get any animation effect, and (b) you get partially-filled ellipses. You could mitigate (b) by limiting the values of the progress bar in code (ie. round to nearest *x*%), however to solve (a) I think you'd be looking at a new control subclassed from the existing **ProgressBar**.